# The problem of extracting the error message of Class-level constraints

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have created a custom validation annotation to check if the password and confirm password are equal. All the things work fine, but the only issue is I cannot get the field name anymore since it is a **class-level constraint** instead of **field**. I only can use the `getAllErrors()` to get the default message. (Refer to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYUjX.png))

### AddUserDTO

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ConfirmPassword
public class AddUsersEntityDTO {

    //...blablabla

    @NotBlank(message ="Password is required")
    @Size(min = 6, message = "Password must be more than 5 characters")
    public String password;

    @NotBlank(message ="Confirm Password is required")
    public String confirmPassword;
}
```

### Validator

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ConfirmPasswordValidation.class)
public @interface ConfirmPassword {

    String message() default "Confirm password is not same with the password";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

```
public class ConfirmPasswordValidation implements ConstraintValidator<ConfirmPassword, AddUsersEntityDTO> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfirmPassword constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(AddUsersEntityDTO addUsersEntityDTO, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return addUsersEntityDTO.getConfirmPassword().equals(addUsersEntityDTO.getPassword());
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are using two different field, how do you know to which field it relates? BTW you already know that for that error the trouble fields are password and/or confirmation password

Comment: Adding on to what rascio said: If your validation doesn't look for any one specific field, then what field name would you be expecting to be able to get? If the answer is "password" or "confirmPassword", then you should ask yourself if the validation really belongs at the class level, or if it belongs on whichever one of those two fields.

Comment: I m not able to get "password" field right if I make it belongs to "confirmpassword" field. That is why I make it belongs at the class level in order to get both of the fields and then compare it. Or can we assign the field name for the class level to let it knows this belongs to the "confirmpassword" field?

Comment: @JackNoob You can hardcode it into the error message, sure. But really you need to tell us what your expectations are (and add them into the question). For example, you could say "I want it so that when I call `getFieldError("password").getDefaultMessage()` that it returns <message1>, and when I call `getFieldError("confirmPassword").getDefaultMessage()`, it returns <message2>. How can I accomplish this?".